# Create a new revision automatically on edit

Tags: nodes

When a node is edited I want to always create a new revision. I do not want people to be able to turn this off. How can I do this?

Comment: admin/content/node-type/[node-type] look at 'Process' fieldset

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To enabled automatic revision creation go to the content type page (admin/content/node-type) and select edit for whatever content type you wish to have revision created automatically.

Under the workflow fieldset there's going to be an option "Create new revision" make sure you check that box and save your content type settings.

Now under your permissions (admin/user/permissions) be sure to not to give your users the "administer nodes" permission. This will prevent them from overwriting that option.

Comment: Is this for drupal 6 only?

Comment: This works for D7 as well. Check also [Revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning) module, which allows the control over the workflow.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few different ways to do this. Assuming you want to avoid to disable the *administer nodes* permission for users, the easiest way is probably to turn off access to the *Create new revision* checkbox creating a custom module with the following code.

```php
function sandbox_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Node forms have an ID of the form CONTENTTYPE_node_form. Modify only those forms.
  if (strstr($form_id, '_node_form') === FALSE) {
    return;
  }

  if (isset($form['revision_information'])) {
    $form['revision_information']['revision']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

In this way, users don't have the ability to change the default value of the checkbox, which is set on the settings page for each content type.